# iframe in Chrome doesn't work when a 404 NOT FOUND is returned, but does for 200

Tags: iframe, http-status-code-404

I have a simple iframe on a page showing a SharePoint library. Don't go telling me to post this over on SharePoint board, ignore that for now.

The page will return a 404 NOT FOUND but SharePoint displays a pretty Page Not Found page (of which we've customized). When this happens, the users cannot see the content of the iframe. Chrome errors with:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)`

Once the file has been placed in SharePoint, and the 404 is fixed, then they can see the contents of the iframe.

The big problem is that this is working on my computer, I see the SP Page Not Found error, no one else does. I don't know why. We've since added both the parent site and SharePoint to the Trusted Sites in Internet Options but it still doesn't work. Assuming there is nothing needed to be changed on the HTML of the parent page or SharePoint, what on the client computers need to be changed?

Comment: Have you looked in the network inspector to see if the 404 response actually contains the custom 404 HTML?  If it does not then its a SP issue if it does then its a Chrome issue

Comment: SP is returning a 404

Request URL:https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/obc-cases/Documents/folder
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 NOT FOUND

Comment: Why does it work on my computer, and another developers, but not on anyone elses

Comment: Looking at the page outside of the iframe, I see the 404 occur and then the page reloads with the SP Page Not Found, with all 200s. Appears iframe is immediately denying the rest to happen after the 404

Comment: funny enough, IE is erroring in the same way, even on my computer. I hate IE. But we only care about chrome

Comment: appears this is a "by design" feature. Since the 404 goes first the iframe catches that and stops. :(